# Ideals and homorphism in Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $S$ be a sub-ring in a ring $R$, and $I$ is an ideal in $R$. The intersection between $I$ and $S$ is $\{0\}$. prove that $S$ is a homormphism with $R / I$.

The last sentence means that there is a homomorphism map between $S$ and $R /I$.

Comment: Welcome to math.se!  [Here are some tips on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Comment: Do you  mean the intersection of $I$ and $S$ is $\{0\}$? Do you mean $R/I$?  And what does the last sentence mean?

Comment: yes I mean it. the last sentence mean that there is a homomorphism map between S and R /I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map $\phi:S\to R/I$, defined as $\phi(s)=s+I$.